# Why metadata is ignored when write a CMYK image?

Tags: twelvemonkeys

I am trying to write a CMYK image with `imageio-jpeg`.I want to keep the dpi same as the original image.I tried as follows.

```
IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(image), param);
Element tree = (Element) imageMetadata.getAsTree(JAVAX_IMAGEIO_JPEG_IMAGE_1_0);
IIOMetadataNode jpegMeta = new IIOMetadataNode(JAVAX_IMAGEIO_JPEG_IMAGE_1_0);
jpegMeta.appendChild(new IIOMetadataNode("JPEGVariety"));
jpegMeta.appendChild(tree.getElementsByTagName("markerSequence").item(0));
metadata.mergeTree(JAVAX_IMAGEIO_JPEG_IMAGE_1_0, jpegMeta);

writer.setOutput(output);
try {
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(im, null, metadata), param);
} finally {
writer.dispose();
    output.flush();
}
```

Finally, `com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter#writeCMYK` was called.In the `writeCMYK` method, `image.metadata` is never used, only `delegate.getDefaultImageMetadata(destinationType, param)` can be found here.How can I set up a metadata when I write a CMYK image?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA3by.png)

Comment: Hi David! I don't see how your code is supposed to set the DPI... Is the DPI contained in the `markerSequence` of some original image? Anyway, it seems you have found a missing feature in our library, that doesn't preserve metadata when writing CMYK. I suggest you file an enhancement request and perhaps a PR to fix it.

Comment: Hi Harald K!The DPI is contained in `Exif` metadata.As [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html#image) **Native Metadata Format Tree Structure and Editing** mentioned.I cheked the `unknown` maker and found the DPI information.I tried to modify the `imageio-jpep` code locally and it worked.I have submitted a request [link](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/852).Thanks!

Comment: For the record, the JPEG plugin is now fixed so you can write metadata with CMYK data. 